# Which Question about plotting a location on a map.

Tags: plotting, geographics, geodesy

I am plotting the wind speed vectors of hurricane Harvey on a graph and I want to add a dot located at coordinates of Dallas.

```
 Monitor[windvectordata = 
 Table[{GeoPosition[{i, j}], 
 WindVectorData[GeoPosition[{i, j}], 
 DateObject[{2017, 8, 17}, TimeObject[{100, 0}]]]}, {i, 25.376, 
 40.958, 2}, {j, -106.429, -87.6, 2}];, {i, j}]

 ls = ListStreamPlot[
 Cases[{Flatten[Reverse[#[[1, 1]]]], QuantityMagnitude[#[[2]]]} & /@
  Flatten[windvectordata, 1], {_, {_?NumberQ, _?NumberQ}}]];
 arrows = Cases[ls, Arrow[_], Infinity]; GeoGraphics[{Yellow, 
 Arrowheads[Small], arrows} , GeoBackground -> "Satellite"]
```

[image]

How do you plot a point located at Dallas whose coordinates are at `{32.7942, -96.7655}`. I would like just a dot and not a flag or `GeoMarker`. Thank you to anyone who would help. (And if anyone also knows how to color the arrows corresponfing to`QuantityMagnitdude` that would be very helpful too).

Comment: `Point` should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?:

```
ls = ListStreamPlot[
 Cases[{Flatten[Reverse[#[[1, 1]]]], QuantityMagnitude[#[[2]]]} & /@
  Flatten[windvectordata, 1], {_, {_?NumberQ, _?NumberQ}}],
 StreamColorFunction -> 
Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, 
 Blend[{Yellow, Purple}, Rescale[n, {0, 1}]]], 
 StreamColorFunctionScaling -> {False, False, False, False, True}];
arrows = Cases[ls, Arrow[_], Infinity]; GeoGraphics[
PrependTo[
 ls[[1, 2]], {{Red, PointSize[0.02], 
Point@GeoPosition[
  Entity["City", {"Dallas", "Texas", 
    "UnitedStates"}]], {GeoStyling[Opacity[0]] , 
 GeoBoundsRegion[{{Quantity[25.5, "AngularDegrees"], 
    Quantity[39.5, "AngularDegrees"]}, {Quantity[-106.5, 
     "AngularDegrees"], Quantity[-88.5, "AngularDegrees"]}}]}}}], 
GeoBackground -> "Satellite"]
```

[image]